# Is it possible to randomly *remove* a percentage/number of items from a list & then *append* them to another list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I am new to python and programming, so apologies in advance.  I know of remove(), append(), len(), and rand.rang (or whatever it is), and I believe I would need those tools, but it's not clear to me *how* to code it.

What I would like to do is, while looping or otherwise accessing List_A, randomly select an index within List_A, remove the selected_index from List_A, and then append() the selected_index to List_B.

I would like to randomly remove only up to a *certain percentage* (or real number if this is impossible) of items from List A.

Any ideas??  Is what I'm describing possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? If you truly can't even start this, I suggest you look up some basic tutorials - StackOverflow giving you a solution won't help you learn.

Comment: The only valid answer for this question would be «yes»

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the input list, I'd shuffle it, then remove `n` items from that list, adding those to the other list:

```
from random import shuffle

def remove_percentage(list_a, percentage):
    shuffle(list_a)
    count = int(len(list_a) * percentage)
    if not count: return []  # edge case, no elements removed
    list_a[-count:], list_b = [], list_a[-count:]
    return list_b
```

where `percentage` is a float value between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Demo:

```
>>> list_a = range(100)
>>> list_b = remove_percentage(list_a, 0.25)
>>> len(list_a), len(list_b)
(75, 25)
>>> list_b
[1, 94, 13, 81, 23, 84, 41, 92, 74, 82, 42, 28, 75, 33, 35, 62, 2, 58, 90, 52, 96, 68, 72, 73, 47]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a random index `i` of some element in `listA`, then you can easily move it from A to B using:

```
listB.append(listA.pop(i))
```

Comment: do you know if pop(i) removes the item from List_A for good?  I thought pop() just returned the item (last item unless specified), but does return == remove in that context?

Comment: @BeeSmears: Try [reading the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: Or try it at the interactive console. One of Python's strengths is that it is so interactive; if you don't take advantage of this, you are missing out.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: What is "the interactive console"?  Is that the shell?  I've googled around for the term but haven't found anything that clearly explains what it is and how I can use it -- and based on your description, I'd love to use it.  Can you recommend a site or just offer a brief explanation?  Thank you for any thoughts/help.

Comment: also the answer to my question re: pop(i), from Alex Martelli's _Python in a Nutshell_: pop(i) returns the value at index i and *removes* it from List.  if i is omitted, pop() returns and removes the last item in the List, and raises an exception if the List is empty or i is an invalid index in L.  I am leaving that description here b/c I find the docs less clear and for any future beginners who find this.

Comment: @BeeSmears - open a shell window, the one where you can type commands like 'dir' (on Windows) or 'ls' (on Linux), and type 'python'. This will start an interactive interpreter session that you can use to try out simple commands. Try `z = list("ABCDE")` to quickly create a simple list. Now do `z.pop(3)` - the letter 'D' will be printed, because that is the value returned by calling `pop`. Now type `print z` if you are using Python 2.x, or `print (z)` if you are using Python 3.x. `D` is gone, because `pop` removed it.

Comment: oh that's awesome.  I've used that shell but never to quickly test functionality like that.  Thanks a mil, Paul.

Answer (score 1):

1) Calculate how many elements you want to remove, call it `k`.

2) `random.randrange(len(listA))` will return a random number between 0 and len(listA)-1 inclusive, e.g. a random index you can use in listA.

3) Grab the element at that index, remove it from listA, append it to listB.

4) Repeat until you have removed `k` elements.

Comment: `randint(a, b)` gives you a value in the range [a, b] (so b is *included*). This means you can pick `len(listA)` which would be out of range.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I think I've been bitten by this in the past :)

Comment: `random.randrange()` won't include the endpoint and, like `range()` you can pass in only the end value. `random.randrange(len(listA))` would do nicely here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, maybe that was the function I was thinking of. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lis = range(100)
>>> per = .30 
>>> no_of_items = int( len(lis) * per) #number of items in 30 percent 
>>> lis_b = []
>>> for _ in xrange(no_of_items):
       ind = random.randint(0,len(lis)-1)  #selects a random index value
       lis_b.append(lis.pop(ind))     #pop the item at that index and append to lis_b 
...     
>>> lis_b
[73, 32, 82, 68, 90, 19, 3, 49, 21, 17, 30, 75, 1, 31, 80, 48, 38, 18, 99, 98, 4, 20, 33, 29, 66, 41, 64, 26, 77, 95]
```

Comment: Perhaps `random.randrange(len(lis))` would be more succint.